# Calculation based on user input (c++ school project)

Tags: c++, type-conversion, currency

Hi everyone I am creating a simple c++ program to write user input to a text file in addition to calculating the information received. So far I am trying to convert dollars to yen, but for some reason I am at a roadblock where I am unable to figure out what is preventing the program from compiling the information.

```
//Dollars to Yen Project

#include <cstring>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    float dollars, yen;

public:
    void store(float);
    float convert();
};

void A::store(float dollars1)

{
    dollars = dollars1;
}

float A::convert() //mutators used

{
    yen = dollars*0.0089;
    return yen;
}

int main()

{

    float dollars;
    float yen;
    cout << "Welcome to Japan, you will need to convert Dollars into Yen to spend money here\n" << endl;
    string b;
    while (1)

    {

        cout << "Enter the amount in dollars to be converted\n";
        cin >> b;
        system("pause");
        if (b.find_first_not_of("1234567890.-") != string::npos) //input check validity
        {

            cout << "invalid number:" << b << endl;

        }

        else

        {

            break;

        }
    }

    float r = atof(b.c_str());
    A a;
    a.store(r);
    float c = a.convert();

    stringstream ss;
    ss << c;

    string s1 = ss.str();
    ofstream prog;

    prog.open("money.txt");
    prog << "The required amount of Yen is " + s1;
    prog.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by something preventing your program from calculating? Compile error? Runtime error? Invalid results?

Comment: Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit your question to give us more details, like some example input, and the expected and actual output from that input. I also suggest you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And if you have build errors, then please copy them (as text, in full and complete) and paste them into the question (without modifications).

Comment: there is some GHOST sitting in your computer and thats the truth

Answer (score 0):

You first create the object for Class 'A' and then call the method.

```
A a; // object declaration
a=new A(); // object Creation

     or
A a=new A();
```

and then call the methods like,
    a.store(r); a.convert();